# Select compound paths under a path but keep edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, mask, word-cloud

Background: I've created a word cloud, and I'd like to clip it to a predefined path. The problem is that words on the edge are getting trimmed halfway, I'd like to keep the whole word.
The question is: How can I select whole objects under a path **the whole object**, I've already tried the pathfinder tool and the clipping mask, but they both "cut" the word.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Surely if you exclude any objects that aren't completely within the clipping mask then your clipping mask isn't really doing much? That's the whole point of a clipping mask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Draw your intended path in any way you like;
2. Select the move tool (black arrow, hotkey <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>;
3. Select your path and then <kbd>Right-click</kbd>;
4. Choose <kbd>Make Guides</kbd>;
5. Choose the lasso tool (<kbd>Q</kbd>);
6. Click and drag the lasso along your newly-made guide shape;
7. Choose <kbd>Select > Inverse</kbd>;
8. Choose <kbd>Object > Hide > Selection</kbd>;

This way, you select all objects outside of your guide, to then hide them. BE warned that the Lasso tool won't snap to the guide you just made, so you'll have to be a bit precise with your selection.

Comment: But that will still only select objects completely outside the path? Not objects *partially* outside the path

Comment: @Cai I took away from the question that that was the intention: hiding only objects completely outside the path.

Comment: "The problem is that words on the edge are getting trimmed halfway, I'd like to keep the whole word" i.e. the problem is objects partially in/out of the clipping path... although that still confuses me. I don't know.

Comment: @Cai according to the checkmark next to my answer, I think I was right ;)